# Is there any way to make image with text shadow in PHP with GD?

Tags: php, image, gd, imagick, drawimage

I've made a tool in which user will type the text & script will make image of that text, but getting issue with text shadow, I wants to make image with text shadow but GB library `shadowImage` function only place the shadow of image not for text,

Here is the image which I got now

[image]

But I wants like that

[image]

Is there anyone know any way so I can make image like that?

here is my method with I used to create it,

```
public function render()
{
    $this->_image = new Imagick;

    if(!$this->text)
    {
        $this->_image->newImage(1, 1, 'white');
        return;
    }

    $draw = new ImagickDraw();
    $color = new ImagickPixel($this->color);
    $background = new ImagickPixel($this->surfaceColor);

    /* Font properties */
    $draw->setStrokeAntialias(true);
    $draw->setTextAntialias(true);
    $draw->setFontSize($this->fontSize);
    $draw->setFillColor($color);
    $draw->setFont(Model_Tool_Font::find($this->font_id)->getFontPath($this->bold, $this->italic));

    /* Border ? */
    if ($this->borderWidth)
    {
        $draw->setStrokeColor($this->borderColor);
        $draw->setStrokeWidth($this->borderWidth * $this->fontSize * self::BORDER_WIDTH_MULTIPLIER );
    }

    /* Get font metrics */
    $metrics = $this->_image->queryFontMetrics($draw, $this->text);
    /* Sizing calculations */
    $width  = $metrics['textWidth'];
    $height = $metrics['textHeight'];
    //respect custom proportions
    if(!$this->maintainProportions  &&  $this->customHeight > 0  &&  $this->customWidth > 0)
    {
        //stretching is better than shrinking (possibly for quality)
        //size limits should be used to constrain size

        $aspect = $this->customWidth / $this->customHeight;
        if($this->customHeight / $height  >  $this->customWidth / $width)
            $height = $width / $aspect;
        else
            $width = $height * $aspect;
    }

    $this->_limitSize($width, $height);
    /* Sizing calculations end */
    //appears to result in bigger image than before sizing?
    if($height > $this->fontSize)
    {
    //update the metrics
        $draw->setFontSize($this->fontSize = $height);
        $metrics = $this->_image->queryFontMetrics($draw, $this->text);
    }

    /* Create text */
    $draw->annotation(0, $metrics['ascender'], $this->text);

    /* Create image */
    $this->_image->newImage($metrics['textWidth'], $metrics['textHeight'], $background);
    $this->_image->drawImage($draw);

    if ($this->reverseCut == 1) {
        $this->_image->flopImage();
    }

    /* Shadow */
    if ($this->shadowOffset)
    {
        $this->shadowOffset = abs((int)$this->shadowOffset);
        $x = $y = 0;
        switch($this->shadowOrient)
        {
            case self::ORIENT_TOP:
                $x =  0;
                $y = -3 - ($this->shadowOffset);
                break;
            case self::ORIENT_TOPRIGHT:
                $x = 2 + ($this->shadowOffset);
                $y = -3 - ($this->shadowOffset);
                break;
            case self::ORIENT_RIGHT:
                $x = 2 + ($this->shadowOffset);
                $y = 0;
                break;
            case self::ORIENT_BOTTOMRIGHT:
                $x = 2 + ($this->shadowOffset);
                $y = 2 + ($this->shadowOffset);
                break;
            case self::ORIENT_BOTTOM:
                $x = 0;
                $y = 2 + ($this->shadowOffset);
                break;
            case self::ORIENT_BOTTOMLEFT:
                $x = -2 - ($this->shadowOffset);
                $y = 2 + ($this->shadowOffset);
                break;
            case self::ORIENT_LEFT:
                $x = -3 - ($this->shadowOffset);
                $y = 0;
                break;
            case self::ORIENT_TOPLEFT:
                $x = -3 - ($this->shadowOffset);
                $y = -3 - ($this->shadowOffset);
                break;
        }

        //transform logical sizes into pixels
        $r = $this->fontSize * self::BORDER_WIDTH_MULTIPLIER;
        $x *= $r;
        $y *= $r;

        $shadow = clone $this->_image;
        $shadow->setImageBackgroundColor( new ImagickPixel( $this->shadowColor ) );
        $shadow->shadowImage( 96, 0.5, 0, 0);
        if($x || $y) {
            $geo = $this->_image->getImageGeometry();
            $currentImage = $this->_image->getImage();
            $this->_image->newImage($geo['width'] + abs($x), $geo['height'] + abs($y), 'none');

            $shift_x = $shift_y = 0;

            if($x < 0) {
                $shift_x = -$x;
                $x = 0;
            }

            if($y < 0) {
                $shift_y = -$y;
                $y = 0;
            }
            $this->_image->compositeImage( $currentImage, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER , $shift_x, $shift_y);

        }
        $this->_image->compositeImage( $shadow, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DSTOVER , $x, $y);

    }
    $this->_image->resizeImage($width, $height, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 0.9, $this->maintainProportions);

}
```

Comment: Simply print the same text but without yellow border and slightly shifted right and down *before* you print text with yellow border.

Comment: Really thanks for your comment, can you please share any code sample for me so I can get your point, if you wants to show my code then I'd like to share my function here.

Comment: Yes, it would be easier with the code you already have.

Comment: I've edit the question & add my method in which I rander the image.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek is there anything in it you could help me?

Comment: @RyanVincent I've tired it already, also this function is for to create text on image but if you check my code, I've text from which I create an image, I need that text with text shadow and then make an image from it.

Comment: Your code is accessing properties of the object but they are not defined here. Either simplify the code or add the definitions so people can copy and run your code.

Comment: @PetrHejda I'll give you full class of mine with all the variables, Can we come on chat window?

Comment: Just create an un-decorated version of your font (no yellow borders) and draw it first, to the right and slightly below.  You should be able to do this if you have already gotten this far with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use Imagick::annotateImage to draw the text with shadow color and shadow offset, then draw text again in your desired position. modified code below copied from [php Imageick manual](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.annotateimage.php)

```
<?php
    /* Create some objects */
    $image = new Imagick();
    $draw = new ImagickDraw();
    $pixel = new ImagickPixel( 'white' );

    /* New image */
    $image->newImage(800, 75, $pixel);


    /* Font properties */
    $draw->setFont('Bookman-DemiItalic');
    $draw->setFontSize( 30 );

    $offset_x = 3;
    $offset_y = 3;

    /* Black shadow */
    $draw->setFillColor('black');
    /* Create text */
    $image->annotateImage($draw, 10+$offset_x, 45+$offset_y, 0, 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog');

    /* Yellow Test */
    $draw->setFillColor('yellow');
    /* Create text */
    $image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 45, 0, 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog');

    /* Give image a format */
    $image->setImageFormat('png');

    /* Output the image with headers */
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    echo $image;

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get reference from here [[GitHub Repository]](https://github.com/andrewgjohnson/imagettftextblur). The code is reproduced as below

```
/*
 * imagettftextblur v1.0.0
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2013 Andrew G. Johnson  <andrew@andrewgjohnson.com>
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 *
 * @author Andrew G. Johnson <andrew@andrewgjohnson.com>
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2013 Andrew G. Johnson <andrew@andrewgjohnson.com>
 * @link http://github.com/andrewgjohnson/imagettftextblur
 * @license http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php The MIT License
 * @version 1.0.0
 * @package imagettftextblur
 *
 */

if (!function_exists('imagettftextblur'))
{
    function imagettftextblur(&$image,$size,$angle,$x,$y,$color,$fontfile,$text,$blur_intensity = null)
    {
        $blur_intensity = !is_null($blur_intensity) && is_numeric($blur_intensity) ? (int)$blur_intensity : 0;
        if ($blur_intensity > 0)
        {
            $text_shadow_image = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($image),imagesy($image));
            imagefill($text_shadow_image,0,0,imagecolorallocate($text_shadow_image,0x00,0x00,0x00));
            imagettftext($text_shadow_image,$size,$angle,$x,$y,imagecolorallocate($text_shadow_image,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF),$fontfile,$text);
            for ($blur = 1;$blur <= $blur_intensity;$blur++)
                imagefilter($text_shadow_image,IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
            for ($x_offset = 0;$x_offset < imagesx($text_shadow_image);$x_offset++)
            {
                for ($y_offset = 0;$y_offset < imagesy($text_shadow_image);$y_offset++)
                {
                    $visibility = (imagecolorat($text_shadow_image,$x_offset,$y_offset) & 0xFF) / 255;
                    if ($visibility > 0)
                        imagesetpixel($image,$x_offset,$y_offset,imagecolorallocatealpha($image,($color >> 16) & 0xFF,($color >> 8) & 0xFF,$color & 0xFF,(1 - $visibility) * 127));
                }
            }
            imagedestroy($text_shadow_image);
        }
        else
            return imagettftext($image,$size,$angle,$x,$y,$color,$fontfile,$text);
    }
}
```

Here is how to add a shadow:

```
imagettftextblur($image,$size,0,$x + 3,$y + 3,$shadow_color,$font,$string,1); // 1 can be higher to increase blurriness of the shadow
imagettftextblur($image,$size,0,$x,$y,$text_color,$font,$string);
```

Comment: I've tried it but if you look in it then you can see that this function works with an image my concern is that I need to create image from text with text shadow, also if you look at my method in my question, I am used text to create image & on that text I need text shadow but the above function will generate the shadow on image not on the text which is in image.

Answer (score 2):

Draw the text twice. First draw the shadow text slightly to the right and below your text position (without an outline) then draw your text as per normal.