# How to use text stroke effect in image intervention?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, intervention

I am using the Image Intervention package to print text on image. But I want this kind of stroke to be the same as this sample image. How to do that?

https://prnt.sc/sIpJBJNzwQhF

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to make image with text shadow in PHP with GD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35012542/is-there-any-way-to-make-image-with-text-shadow-in-php-with-gd)

Comment: There is always only text shadow, but not 3D texts. I don't think you will get desired effect with GD/Imagick libs

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343771/how-to-stylize-text-with-php-using-gd-imagick